# Swift: filter an array of Element1 [(String, Bool)] to return AND convert to an array of Element2 [String]?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, filter

I have an array of [(userID: String, friendBool: Bool)] that I want to filter AND convert to an array of userID's only [String] (removing the friendBool and therefore changing the element). Is there a function in Swift for doing this?

Currently, I am filtering on the array and then using a for loop on the filtered array [(userID: String, friendBool: Bool)] to convert it to an array of [String]. Is there a better way to do this?

Current Code:

```
    let friendArray = [(userID: String, friendBool: Bool)]()
    let excludeUsers = [String]()

    //Updates with user actions
    var userArrayForTableView = [String]()

    //Filter friendArray
    let newArray = friendArray.filter { (existingFriend) -> Bool in
        return !excludeUsers.contains(existingFriend.userID)
    }

    //Convert array fro [(userID: String, friendBool: Bool)] to [String]
    for existingFriend in newArray {
        userArrayForTableView.append(existingFriend.userID)
    }
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
    //Loaded on ViewDidLoad
    let friendArray = [(userID: String, friendBool: Bool)]()
    let excludeUsers = [String]()

    //Updates with user actions
    var userArrayForTableView = [String]()

    //Filter friendArray
    /*
    Below fitler returns an array of [(userID: String, friendBool: Bool)]...
     but I want a filter to return an array of [String] for just userIDs
    */
    let newArray = friendArray.filter { (existingFriend) -> Bool in
        return !excludeUsers.contains(existingFriend.userID)
    }
    //ERROR HERE because 'newArray' is not [String]
    userArrayForTableView.append(contentsOf: newArray)
```

Comment: If I understood correctly (I might have reversed the output condition): `let result = friendArray.compactMap({ excludeUsers.contains($0.userID) ? nil : $0.userID })`?

Comment: You should *really* create a `User` struct. Tuples are meant for a fast and convenient  way to return a few values from a function. They're much more limited than structs/classes (they don't have names, they can't conform to protocols, they can't have methods, computed properties, subscripts defined on them), and they aren't protective of their innards. Under this current setup, nothing stops you from making a value like `(userID: "Obviously not a real user ID", friendBool: true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `compactMap()`?

In a certain way, it can be understood as a `filter()` (that you are already using) + `map()` (which is the loop `for existingFriend in newArray` in the first solution)

```
let userArrayForTableView = friendArray.compactMap({ (existingFriend) in 
    if excludeUsers.contains($0.userID) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return existingFriend.id
    }
})
```

In a shorter way:

```
let userArrayForTableView = friendArray.compactMap({ excludeUsers.contains($0.userID) ? nil : $0.userID })
```

Comment: Thank you! This is even better than what what I was looking for haha. Perfect. One quick question: if it returns nil for a value, will the array be [id1, nil, id3] .. or will it be [id1, id3]? I'm hoping for the latter because I will use the resulting array in a tableview and do not want nil cells.

Comment: If the closure returns nil, then it won’t add the value to the array.